# Derived (non-commutative) geometry, geometric constructions in explicit form

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm interested in the following construction. Start with derived category of coherent sheaves  witch equivalent to derived category of representations of some dg-algebra. Quasi-isomorphic dg-algebras gives the same "space" (or sheaves on "space") from derived point of view. So I regard $A_\infty$ algebras as natural data for derived non-commutative geometry. So, commutative algebraic constructions have counterparts on  $A_\infty$ side. There are explicit description of localization, gluing, blowing up etc. for $A_\infty$ algebras?  References are welcome, thanks.