# D-modules as quantization of modules on cotangent bundle

Tags: d-modules, quantization, rt.representation-theory

If we have filtration on D-module compatible with some good filtration on differential operators sheaf then adjoint graded module is module over functions on cotangent bundle. So morally D-module is quantization of something lying on cotangent bundle. There is some rigid statement around this? 
 Some concrete expectations. From here [Derived (non-commutative) geometry, geometric constructions in explicit form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123357/derived-non-commutative-geometry-geometric-constructions-in-explicit-form) we could get some dg-algebras for derived categories of D-modules  and coherent sheaves on cotangent bundle resp., for their suitable models (~quasi-isomorphism) can we observe first thing as "quantization" of second precisely on the level of differential? Second. Peoples in geometric representation theory often work with coherent sheaves on cotangent bundle of flag varieties, but by the pointed view their constructions must admit quantization, does such thoughts been exploited? It is can be funny if geometric representation construction was connected with some quantum group, because D-modules on flag variety is almost representations of lie algebra

Comment: look also at quantization of lagrangian submanifolds

Comment: I'm not really sure what question you're asking (perhaps the issue is alluded to in your handle).  Geometric representation theorists have certainly noticed that D-modules are quantized coherent sheaves on the cotangent bundle and exploited this fact.  So what about it?

Comment: D-modules on flag varieties have been extensively studied, e.g., in Beilinson-Bernstein.  There is also work connected to quantum groups using a quantum flag variety, in work by Rosenberg and later Backland-Kremnitzer.  In other words, such thoughts have been exploited in the past.

Comment: I know nothing about geometric representation theory and was interested in that from Khovanov homology side. There is construction by Joel Kamnitzer in which cotangent bundle to non-complete (generalized) flag variety plays a role. So 'there is' some quantization of construction by move from sheaves on cotangent bundle to d-modules. So I want example of quantization of some construction in sheaves to d-modules where output is deformed first one.

Comment: If I assume the question is asking something along the lines of what information on the cotangent bundle recovers the D-module then this is going to be very hard. For example, to make a statement precise one will need to dive into the depths of the proof of the codimension three conjecture of Kashiwara and Vilonen: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1209.5124. To make things even harder this conjecture, well theorem, only applies to regular holonomic D-modules. I have not heard of any proposed conjecture for non-holonomic  D-modules...